# C# packet structure system

Tags: c#, tcp, udp, console-application, packet

I am working on a packet system (UDP or TCP, either way is fine) but I came to the conclusion that my current (TCP) system is really awefull.

Basicly, I'm sending a packet that looks like this:

```
string packet = "LOGIN_AUTH;TRUE"
IPAddress target = IPAddress.Parse(endPoint);
// Send packet
```

When I recieve the packet in my client, I use this to determine the packet type:

```
string[] splitPacket = packet.Split(';');

if (splitPacket[0] == "LOGIN_AUTH" && splitPacket[1] == "TRUE")
   authLogin(packet); //Does stuff like loading the next screen
```

But I'm sure there must be a better way to do this, because of this thread:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/79660898-aeee-4c7b-8cba-6da55767daa1/ (post 2)

I'm just wondering if someone could give me a push in the right direction on what I should to categorize the packets in a way that's more easy on the eye.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: I did some research, but I cant find a solution to my problem in WCF. So once again, what is the best way to create a packet structure, and how do I utilize it?

I don't want to recreate a protocol, just something like this:

```
public string sepChar = ";"
public static struct loginPacket
{
    string type;
    string username;
    string password;
}

public void reqLogin()
{
    lock (_locker)      //Need to make it thread-safe in this case
    {
         loginPacket.type = "login";
         loginPacket.username = "username";
         loginPacket.password = "password;

         sendPacket(loginPacket);
    }
}

public void sendPacket(string packet)
{
    // Script to send packet using the struct information
}
```

I hope that's detailed enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend WCF; if not now, decide to learn it in the future. It has a huge learning curve because it covers not only what you're trying to do, but so many other things.

If you just want a quick-and-dirty solution, then you could use binary serialization. To take this approach, you'll need to define your message types in a dll shared between client and server. Then, remember to use a form of [message framing](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/04/message-framing.html) so that the messages don't get munged up in transit.

Things get more complex when you consider versioning. Eventually you'll want to use WCF.

Comment: Thank you, I'll probably learn WCF. But at the moment I'm stuck with Visual C# *cough*express edition*cough*. That's why I'm looking for a way to divide the packet into parts: SENDER;ACTION;PARAM. And then, when I receive the packet I can just check the ACTION and process the parameters depending on the action. I'm just looking for a better way than to just Split() the packet by it's seperation character. (; in this case)

Answer (score 1):

I have used my own communication protocol over TCP 2 years ago, about the base packet class:

```
public enum PacketType {Login, Hello, FooBar}
public class Packet
{
    public long Size;
    public PacketType PacketType;
}
public class LoginPacket : Packet
{
    public string Login;
    public string Password;
}
```

I do not agree with Size property... because you will only know packet size AFTER it was serialized with binaryFormater. I have used other method, first i serialized packet object and then before putting this byte[] in network stream i wrote BitConverter.GetBytes(SerializedPacketMemoryStream.Length) before each packet bytes.
2nd thing to consider, is that you need to create temp buffer for received bytes[] and wait until you receive full packet and only then desirialize it.
I can send you my client\server code part, it's not very clean i wrote it when i just started learning C#, but it is 100% stable, tested for 3 years in production environment.

Comment: And maybe it's better to try WCF? When i was writing this code there were no WCF yet, only .NET remoting, and it wasn't working with NAT connections (Remoting tries to esteblish new connection to client for callbacks). So i was forced to write my own communication layer.

Comment: Good explenation. I guess I'll have to start learning WCP then, it sounds like alot of work, but more managable.

Answer (score 0):

[protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) might be what you want.

Here's the .NET port: [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/)